# In Swift why is it that structures declared as constants are unable to update variable properties?

Tags: swift

If you have a Structure with variable properties and you set an instance of that Structure to a constant, you can not update its variable properties whereas if you have a Class with variable properties and set an instance of that Class to a constant, you can update its variable properties:

```
struct StructPoint {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

class ClassPoint {

    var x: Int
    var y: Int

    init(x: Int, y: Int) {
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    }
}

var s = StructPoint(x: 2, y: 3)
let s2 = StructPoint(x: 2, y: 3)

s.x = 3    // allowed
s2.x = 5   // not allowed

var p = ClassPoint(x: 2, y: 3)
let p2 = ClassPoint(x: 2, y: 3)

p.x = 4    // allowed
p2.x = 4   // allowed
```

Why is this the case? I suspect it has something to do with Classes being a reference type and Structures being a value type, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this behavior is the result of Classes being reference types and Structures being value types.

The section on Classes as Reference Types explains it with a simple example:

```
let tenEighty = VideoMode()
tenEighty.resolution = hd
tenEighty.interlaced = true
tenEighty.name = "1080i"
tenEighty.frameRate = 25.0
```

> Note that tenEighty and alsoTenEighty are declared as constants,
>   rather than variables. However, you can still change
>   tenEighty.frameRate and alsoTenEighty.frameRate because the values of
>   the tenEighty and alsoTenEighty constants themselves do not actually
>   change. tenEighty and alsoTenEighty themselves do not “store” the
>   VideoMode instance—instead, they both refer to a VideoMode instance
>   behind the scenes. It is the frameRate property of the underlying
>   VideoMode that is changed, not the values of the constant references
>   to that VideoMode.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID89

Here are a few other good resources to explain reference versus value types from other languages. Even though they are not specifically about Swift, the same concepts apply:

[Joseph Albahari's explanation of value vs. reference types in C#](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

[Jon Skeet's explanation of references and values in .NET](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html)

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had seen that in the book somewhere and couldn't find it.